# SQLite INSERT Statement

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert

I have created the following insert method which works fairly well but I know it could be more efficient.  Could someone show me how to convert this method to use parameters and/or increase its efficiency?

```
public static void SQLiteTableINSERT(string tableName)
{
    int colCount = 0;
    using (SQLiteConnection Conn = new SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConn.Conn))
    {
        using (SQLiteTransaction sqliteTrans = Conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                DataTableColumnNames();

                string query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(";

                foreach (string name in DtColumns)
                {
                    query += "[" + name + "]";
                    ++colCount;

                    if (colCount < DtColumns.Count())
                        query += ",";
                }

                query += ")";
                query += " VALUES(";

                for (int i = 0; i < LocalDataSet.LocalDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = query;

                    foreach (DataColumn col in LocalDataSet.LocalDs.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {
                        string temp = LocalDataSet.LocalDs.Tables[0].Rows[i][col, DataRowVersion.Current].ToString();

                        if (temp == "True")
                            cmd.CommandText += 1;

                        else if (temp == "")
                            cmd.CommandText += 0;

                        if (temp != "True" && temp != "")
                            cmd.CommandText += "'" +temp + "'";

                        cmd.CommandText += ",";
                    }

                    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Remove(cmd.CommandText.LastIndexOf(","));

                    cmd.CommandText += ")";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            sqliteTrans.Commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should switch this to using a prepared statement, then binding the data to parameters in that prepared statement. The basics are explained here for C/C++:

http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

I suspect that you are using dotConnect so you might want to refer to this for your specific example:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Parameters.html

Same principle applies. You write the SQL as a single string constant that is easy to read, review and modify in your source code. Then you send that SQL command to SQLite along with a set of data elements to replace each of the parameters. This technique makes your code clearer and helps to avoid SQL injection attacks, or mixups.

Comment: So I changed my code around a bit to where I am inserting (?) in my VALUES portion of the insert statement and I have attempted to update my code to use parameters but I keep getting the exception:
 "Insufficient parameters supplied to the command"

I looked through my code and everything appears to be right, can anyone see something wrong with this?

I am going to post the code in an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like the error you would get if you don't supply one data item for every ?. For instance, if you had three ? but only pass two parameters. In C/C++ it might possibly have something to do with a null string parameter, or even a type mismatch.