# Improving SQLite Performance

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Well i have a `file.sql` that contains `20,000` of insert commands

Sample From the `.sql` file

> INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
>   (1,-400,400,3,154850,'Text',590628,'TEXT',1610,'TEXT',79);
>
> INSERT INTO `table` VALUES
>   (39,-362,400,3,111659,'Text',74896,'TEXT',0,'TEXT',14);

And i am using the following code to create an in memory Sqlite database and pull the values into it then calculate the time elapsed

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=:memory:"))
{
    conn.Open();

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
    {
        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {

                cmd.CommandText = File.ReadAllText(@"file.sql");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    var timeelapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds <= 60
                          ? stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds"
                          : Math.Round(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds/60) + " minutes";
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Time elapsed {0}", timeelapsed));
    conn.Close();
}
```

Things i have tried

1. Using file database instead of memory one.
2. Using begin transaction and commit transaction [AS SHOWN IN MY CODE].
3. Using Firefox's extension named `SQLite Manager` to test whether the
   slowing down problem is from the script; However, I was surprised
   that the same `20,000` lines that i am trying to process using my code
   has been pulled to the database in JUST 4ms!!!.
4. Using `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF`, as well as, `PRAGMA journal_mode =
   MEMORY`.
5. Appending `begin transaction;` and `commit transaction;` to the
   beginning and ending of the `.sql` file respectively.

As the SQLite documentations says : SQLite is capable of processing `50,000` commands per seconds. And that is real and i made sure of it using the `SQLite Manager` [AS DESCRIPED IN THE THIRD SOMETHING THAT I'V TRIED]; However, I am getting my `20,000` commands done in 4 minutes something that tells that there is something wrong.

QUESTION : What is the problem am i facing why is the Execution done very slowly ?!

Comment: Have you tried creating the command object **after** the transaction object?

Comment: I think this is what is done in my code ??

Comment: Have you tried to find out how mnuch time the ReadAllText method takes?

Comment: It only takes a second because when i try to debug the program it only stops for less than a second

Comment: In your code you call `new SQLiteCommand(conn)` before you call `conn.BeginTransaction()`. Try switching between those two lines and see what happens.

Comment: And how long does your execution take?

Comment: Tried that with the same delay

Comment: 4 Minutes in my application.

Comment: While it takes only 4ms when i try to execute in the firefox's extension named SQLite Manager

Comment: Have you tried it with a file-based SQLite DB?

Comment: yea and i have stated that in the `Things I Have Tried` section

Comment: Ah, OK sure. Have you made sure that there are only INSERTs with those 11 parameters? Maybe there's an INSERT that uses multiple VALUES sections and has more than a million entries maybe?

Comment: @Sebastian: No i doubt that and even if true, How is it only finishing in 4ms when it comes to using SQLite Manager in Firefox...

Comment: Try setting `cmd.Transaction=transaction;`

Comment: ooooh, that's very true @IdanArye

Comment: The SAME... This thing gave me headache i don't know why this happens

Comment: OK, one last attempt: Try substituting "var" with the actual types.

Comment: Which System.Data.Sqlite version are you using?

Comment: I think it is : `1.0.84.0`

Comment: I'm sorry, I give up...
SQLite has never been a problem for me

Comment: Could you do me a favor and send me a working, sample project ?. So that i try it .... Maybe it works

Comment: Are you sending all the Inserts in one string?

Comment: @Dzienny: it is actually in a .sql file which must not be a problem as it works very fine when i try it with SQLite Manager in Firefox. So why is it that hell slow when it comes to my code!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right library? This one works for sure: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/

Comment: It's not something silly like 'debug' vs 'release' project configuration is it? Also 4ms is awfully quick to process 20k statements... that's a lot of string data after all, I would double check it's actually doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @MikeTrusov The same speed on both Release and Debug, Also this is how it has been done in SQLite Manager ... only 4ms; However this is not strange because as the Documentation says `it is capable of doing 50,000\s`

Comment: @RuneS It's not like it has hardcoded a slow down algorithm :) So, this number (50,000\s) is more or less meaningless.

Comment: 20k in 4ms is 5mil in 1s which is 100 times more than the advertised 50k in 1s, which is why I'm skeptical. Here's a good blog about it (first thing came up in google search 'sqlite bulk insert'): http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/. So preprocess your file and make a prepared statement.

Comment: @Mike Trusov: man i working in C# not C

Comment: blog shows you benchmark of approaches, language is not relevant there... it tells you that prepared statements are the way to go so you google 'sqlite c# prepared statement' to get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583044/sqlite-insert-statement or if that's not enough then add your specific c# sqlite library into search >.>

Comment: well you are doing it absolutely wrong. you can not set 20000 inserts as a CommandText. OK you may, but that's the reason for you bad performance. Try to split inserts, and create precompiled insert statement and execute them inside transaction and you will get a performance boost.

Comment: @Mike Trusov: Ok i solved it now i am capable of adding 560,000 commands in just 9 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite.Net documentation recommends the following construct for transactions

```
using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=:memory:")) 
{
  conn.Open();
  using(SqliteTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
    using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
    {
      cmd.CommandText = File.ReadAllText(@"file.sql");
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    trans.Commit();
  }
  con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to manipulate the text file contexts to something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (col01, col02, col03, col04, col05, col06, col07, col08, col09, col10, col11)
SELECT 1,-400,400,3,154850,'Text',590628,'TEXT',1610,'TEXT',79
UNION ALL
SELECT 39,-362,400,3,111659,'Text',74896,'TEXT',0,'TEXT',14
;
```

Maybe try "batching them" into groups of 100 as a initial test.

http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

SqlLite seems to support the UNION ALL statement.

Comment: col01, etc, I would put in the real column names of course.  Those are just my placeholders.